# switch statement inside mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I would like to ask if it's possible to have a switch statement inside a php file where it is in mpdf.

this is my switch statement

```
switch($cts){
    case 1:
    echo "Not at all";
    break;
    Case 2:
    echo "Ok";
    break;
    default;
    echo "none";
}
```

but this could not be done in a mpdf.
Help.

Comment: its still just php right? mpdf is just for creating pdfs?

Comment: @nogad it's still in php sir but it's a bit different.

Comment: like this `$html = '<div> </div>';`

Comment: Don't echo, store it to a variable, then use the variable in the `pdf` generation.

Comment: @chris85 how can I put it?>]\

Comment: its not diffirent if its still php

Comment: `echo "Not at all";` becomes `$pdf_value =  "Not at all";` then put it into the `$html` where ever you want it. It's is basically the same you just cant output before the `header` call I presume `mpdf` makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the respective messages in a variable and print it out outside the switch.

```
$msg = '';

switch($cts){
    case 1:
        $msg = "Not at all";
        break;
    case 2:
        $msg = "Ok";
        break;
    default: $msg = "none";  
}

echo $msg;
```

Comment: well ty sir :) I've understand it more now